# Possible Inconsistency Among System Tables

Tags: oracle, system-tables

Is there a reason that there would be a significant difference in the number of records in the DBA_USERS table and the USER$ table?

Comment: Just look at the definition for the DBA_USERS view. Should explain everything

Comment: Yes, "DBA_USERS describes all users of the database."  So if I get an output of DBA_USERS that is about 15 record and a list of USER$ that is about 55 records, my first thought is that there is a problem.  Am I correct?

Comment: When I said "definition" I meant look at the source for the dba_views view to see what query it executes against the user$ internal oracle table

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`USER$` is a table, `DBA_USERS` is a view.

`USER$` contains user and roles while `DBA_USERS` selects only the users.